# What are the alien base building mechanics in OpenXCom

Tags: open-xcom

The flavor text of the "Alien Base" mission mentions that in order to build a base, aliens need to successfully complete several landings in the area. I noticed this behavior in the game: Various UFOs of different sizes simultaneously appear in the same area, and when left alone a new alien base can be found there shortly after. But when some of the UFOs are shot down, no base will be found.

Which ships exactly appear as part of a base building operation and what needs to be done to prevent the base from being built? Do I need to shoot them all down, or are only specific UFOs critical for the base building process? Do I need to shoot them down before they land or can I raid the landed UFOs? When I shoot them down, do I need to clear the crash sites?

Comment: As a partial answer, I know for a fact that once the UFO lands, it has completed its mission regardless of how long it takes them to take off again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the OpenXCom source (notably the data file [Xcom1Ruleset.rul](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Battleship#Alien_Base)), the Alien Base mission proceeds through two phases. The first phase appears sometime between the 4th and 14th day of the month and consists of of a single ship, a small scout. The second phase appears 5 to 15 days later. A quick succession of a medium scout, large scout, two supply ships and a battleship will appear, each 60 minutes apart, excepting the second supply ship which will appear 30 minutes after the first. At the same time the final ship, the battleship spawns, the alien base is created on the map.

There's nothing you can do stop the base from being created. Shooting down or destroying one of these ufos, other than the battleship, will delay the next one appearing by an additional 8 or 9 days. Since in the ships in the second phase appear relatively quickly, I'm not sure how practical it is to shoot any of them down before the battleship arrives. Your only real chance to delay the mission may be to shoot down the first ship.

I'm not sure if these mechanics match those of the original game. The aliens do follow a similar pattern by sending a scout ship or scout ships first. Shooting down these ships may delay or even prevent the base from being built. The one thing that's [known for sure](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Battleship#Alien_Base) about the original game is that the base is created at the same time the battleship ship shows up in the atmosphere. So in that respect at least OpenXCom is faithful to the original.

Also note that Alien infiltration missions follow a similar pattern (except with three phases of single scout ships before the final phase) and also result in a base being created in the nation signing a pact with the aliens. Shooting down these ships only delays the mission from being completed, it never prevents it.